# java swing ui not displaying rebuilt array index out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, swing, indexoutofboundsexception

Okay, I am still very much a Java newbie.   To be honest, this is for a homework assignment, but I am beating my head against the wall right now.  I don't have any idea where to go from here.

I'm writing an inventory program for the assignment, and it MUST use a normal array.  Not an `ArrayList`

The part I am stumped on is the part where you have to add a new entry to the array. I managed that by using `Arrays.copyof` to create a second version of it, then to recopy it to the original with an enhanced length.  It seems to work, through the console I can print my new array no problem, complete with the new entry.  The problem I am encountering is with my gui for it.. Every time I try to display the new entry in my gui I get

> `"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5"`

I'm sure its some stupid mistake I'm making, but I've had a long day and I'm completely stumped on this.

```
package inventoryprogram3;
public class Inventoryprogram3 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {      
       inventoryGui gui = new inventoryGui();
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
package inventoryprogram3;

import java.io.Serializable;

class sItem implements Serializable{
        int itemNumber;
        String itemName; 
        int itemStock;
        double itemPrice;
        double stockTotal;
 public sItem(int iNumber, String iName, int iStock, double iPrice){
        itemNumber = iNumber;
        itemName = iName;
        itemStock = iStock;
        itemPrice = iPrice;
 }
}

public class rBook extends sItem {
    int pCount;
    double rFee;
    public rBook(int iNumber, String iName, int iStock, double iPrice, int pageCount) {
        super(iNumber, iName, iStock, iPrice);
               pCount = pageCount;
               rFee = (iPrice * iStock) * 1.05;        
    }    
}


package inventoryprogram3;


import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class inventoryGui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form inventoryGui
     */
   static int max = 5;
    static rBook[] rpg = new rBook[max];
    double invValue;
    int counter = -1;



    public inventoryGui() {
        initComponents();
        rpg[0] = new rBook(1, "Mutants & Masterminds", 4, 19.99, 200);
        rpg[1] = new rBook(2, "Exalted", 6, 25.99, 542);
        rpg[2] = new rBook(3, "D&D Next", 15, 49.95, 350);
        rpg[3] = new rBook(4, "Eclipse Phase", 3, 28.99, 426);
        rpg[4] = new rBook(5, "The Mutant Epoch", 8, 19.99, 386);
    }



    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        nameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        titleLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        iNumberLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        priceLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        pCountlabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        stockLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        restockLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        entireInventoryLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        restockField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        stockField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        pCountField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        priceField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        iNumberField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        titleField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        inventoryValueLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        inventoryValueField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        nextButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        entireInventoryField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        buttonLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        previousButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        companyLogo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        saveButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        loadButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        addbutton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        deleteButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        modifyButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        searchButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jLabel4.setText("jLabel4");

        jLabel2.setText("jLabel2");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("RPG Inventory Program v0.4");

        nameLabel.setText("Role Playing Game Inventory");

        titleLabel.setText("Title");

        iNumberLabel.setText("Item Number");

        priceLabel.setText("Price");

        pCountlabel.setText("Page Count");

        stockLabel.setText("Copies in Stock");

        restockLabel.setText("Restocking Fee");

        entireInventoryLabel.setText("Value of Entire Inventory");

        restockField.setEditable(false);

        iNumberField.setEditable(false);

        inventoryValueLabel.setText("Inventory Value");

        nextButton.setText("Next");
        nextButton.setToolTipText("Click toDisplay Next Item");
        nextButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                nextButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        entireInventoryField.setEditable(false);

        buttonLabel.setText("Item Display");

        previousButton.setText("Previous");
        previousButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                previousButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        companyLogo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/inventoryprogram3/logo4.png"))); 

        saveButton.setText("Save");
        saveButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                saveButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        loadButton.setText("Clear");
        loadButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                loadButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        addbutton.setText("Add");
        addbutton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                addbuttonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        deleteButton.setText("Delete");
        deleteButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                deleteButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        modifyButton.setText("Modify Current Item");
        modifyButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                modifyButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        searchButton.setText("Search");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(pCountlabel)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(pCountField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(entireInventoryLabel))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(restockLabel)
                                        .addGap(192, 192, 192)
                                        .addComponent(previousButton))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(loadButton)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(addbutton)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(deleteButton)
                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                        .addComponent(modifyButton)
                                        .addGap(12, 12, 12)))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(nextButton)
                                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(saveButton))))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(nameLabel)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(priceLabel)
                                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                            .addComponent(priceField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(titleLabel)
                                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                            .addComponent(titleField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 156, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(iNumberLabel)
                                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                            .addComponent(iNumberField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(searchButton)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(companyLogo)))
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(restockField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(inventoryValueLabel)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(inventoryValueField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(stockLabel)
                                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                    .addComponent(stockField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(entireInventoryField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 121, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(buttonLabel)
                                .addGap(15, 15, 15)))
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {iNumberLabel, pCountlabel, priceLabel, restockLabel, stockLabel, titleLabel});

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {iNumberField, inventoryValueField, pCountField, priceField, restockField, stockField, titleField});

        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(nameLabel)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(titleLabel)
                            .addComponent(titleField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(searchButton))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(iNumberLabel)
                            .addComponent(iNumberField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(priceLabel)
                            .addComponent(priceField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addComponent(companyLogo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(pCountlabel)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(pCountField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(entireInventoryLabel)))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(stockLabel)
                    .addComponent(stockField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(entireInventoryField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(inventoryValueLabel)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(inventoryValueField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(buttonLabel)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(restockLabel)
                    .addComponent(restockField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(previousButton)
                    .addComponent(nextButton))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(saveButton)
                    .addComponent(addbutton)
                    .addComponent(deleteButton)
                    .addComponent(modifyButton)
                    .addComponent(loadButton))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }

    private void nextButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           


        if(counter< max -1){
        counter = counter + 1;
        }
        else{
        counter = 0;
        }
       NumberFormat realMoney = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
       invValue = 0;
        for (int x=0; x < max -1; x++) {

            invValue += rpg[x].itemStock * rpg[x].itemPrice;

       }


        System.out.println(counter);
        titleField.setText(rpg[counter].itemName);
        iNumberField.setText(String.valueOf(rpg[counter].itemNumber));
        pCountField.setText(String.valueOf(rpg[counter].pCount));       
        priceField.setText(String.valueOf(realMoney.format(rpg[counter].itemPrice)));
        stockField.setText(String.valueOf(rpg[counter].itemStock));
        restockField.setText(String.valueOf(rpg[counter].rFee));
        inventoryValueField.setText(String.valueOf(rpg[counter].itemStock * rpg[counter].itemPrice));


        entireInventoryField.setText(String.valueOf(realMoney.format(invValue)));

    }                                          

    private void previousButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        if(counter>= 1){
        counter = counter - 1;
        }
        else{
        counter = max -1;
        }
       NumberFormat realMoney = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
       invValue = 0;
        for (int x=0; x < max -1; x++) {

           invValue += rpg[x].itemStock * rpg[x].itemPrice;

       }



        titleField.setText(rpg[counter].itemName);
        iNumberField.setText(String.valueOf(rpg[counter].itemNumber));
        pCountField.setText(String.valueOf(rpg[counter].pCount));       
        priceField.setText(String.valueOf(realMoney.format(rpg[counter].itemPrice)));
        stockField.setText(String.valueOf(rpg[counter].itemStock));
        restockField.setText(String.valueOf(rpg[counter].rFee));
        inventoryValueField.setText(String.valueOf(rpg[counter].itemStock * rpg[counter].itemPrice));


        entireInventoryField.setText(String.valueOf(realMoney.format(invValue)));
    }                                              

    private void saveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {             
        ObjectOutputStream savefile = null;
       int dirmake = 1;
       do{ 
       try {             
            savefile = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\inventory\\inventory.dat"));
            savefile.writeObject(rpg);
            savefile.close();
            dirmake = 2 ;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            String savePath = "c:\\Inventory";
            Path invPath = Paths.get(savePath);
            try {
                Files.createDirectory(invPath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(inventoryGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
       }while(dirmake == 1);
    }                                          

    private void loadButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

         titleField.setText("");
        iNumberField.setText("");
        pCountField.setText("");       
        priceField.setText("");
        stockField.setText("");
        restockField.setText("");
        inventoryValueField.setText("" );


        entireInventoryField.setText("");

    }                                          

    private void modifyButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

       int mINumber = Integer.parseInt(iNumberField.getText());
       double ss = Double.parseDouble(priceField.getText().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
        rpg[mINumber -1] = new rBook(mINumber, titleField.getText(), Integer.parseInt(stockField.getText()), ss, Integer.parseInt(pCountField.getText()));

    }                                            

    private void addbuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        double ss = Double.parseDouble(priceField.getText().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
        max ++;
        rBook[] rpg2 = Arrays.copyOf(rpg, rpg.length);
        rBook[] rpg = Arrays.copyOf(rpg2, max);
        rpg[max -1] = new rBook(max, titleField.getText(), Integer.parseInt(stockField.getText()), ss, Integer.parseInt(pCountField.getText()));
        System.out.println(max + titleField.getText() + Integer.parseInt(stockField.getText()) + ss + Integer.parseInt(pCountField.getText()));
        counter = -1;
        System.out.println(max);
        for (int x=0; x< max; x++) {
        System.out.println("Item Number:" + rpg[5].itemNumber);
        System.out.println("Rpg Name:" + rpg[5].itemName);
        System.out.println("Copies in stock:" + rpg[5].itemStock);
        System.out.println("Price: $" + (rpg[5].itemPrice));
        System.out.println("Page Count:" + rpg[5].pCount);
        System.out.println("Restocking fee: $" + (rpg[5].rFee));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(rpg.length);
        }

    }                                         

    private void deleteButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             


    }                                            



    public static void main(String args[]) {


        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(inventoryGui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(inventoryGui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(inventoryGui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(inventoryGui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new inventoryGui().setVisible(true);


            }
        });
    }


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton addbutton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel buttonLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel companyLogo;
    private javax.swing.JButton deleteButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField entireInventoryField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel entireInventoryLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField iNumberField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel iNumberLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField inventoryValueField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel inventoryValueLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JButton loadButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton modifyButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel nameLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton nextButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField pCountField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel pCountlabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton previousButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField priceField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel priceLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField restockField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel restockLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton saveButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton searchButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField stockField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel stockLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField titleField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel titleLabel;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't rely on `max`, rely on `rpg.length`.  Also, `static` is not your friend.  An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your problem is, you are shadowing your variables...

```
max ++;
rBook[] rpg2 = Arrays.copyOf(rpg, rpg.length);
rBook[] rpg = Arrays.copyOf(rpg2, max);
```

Here, you've declared `rpg` as a local variable, so any changes you make to it are not seen by the rest of the class.  Try using something more like...

```
rpg = Arrays.copyOf(rpg2, max);
```

instead...

You could also consider using [`System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) instead...but I'd fix you other problems first ;)

```
rBook[] rpg2 = new rBook[rpg.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(rpg, 0, rpg2, 0, rpg.length - 1);
rpg = rpg2;
```

Or something like that...